# Why am I getting memory leaks ? Is there something missing in the following C code?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list

I am trying to write a custom lib in c for a personal project. The lib includes some common data structures. I am allocating the list on the heap and I think I am cleaning up properly, but that is not the case. On running `leaks --atExit --list -- ./main` (mac m1), I am getting a total of 4 leaks in the following code.

```bash
leaks Report Version: 3.0
Process 18747: 221 nodes malloced for 17 KB
Process 18747: 4 leaks for 96 total leaked bytes.
```

Stack trace is as follows:

```bash
Leak: 0x14e7040f0  size=16  zone: MallocStackLoggingLiteZone_0x102a40000   malloc in main  C  main
    Call stack: 0x180c6be50 (dyld) start | 0x1028475a8 (main) main  main.c:38 | 0x180dffd00 (libsystem_malloc.dylib) _malloc_zone_malloc_instrumented_or_legacy

Leak: 0x14e704100  size=16  zone: MallocStackLoggingLiteZone_0x102a40000   malloc in main  C  main
    Call stack: 0x180c6be50 (dyld) start | 0x1028475c4 (main) main  main.c:41 | 0x180dffd00 (libsystem_malloc.dylib) _malloc_zone_malloc_instrumented_or_legacy

Leak: 0x14e704180  size=32  zone: MallocStackLoggingLiteZone_0x102a40000   malloc in node_init  C  main
    Call stack: 0x180c6be50 (dyld) start | 0x10284761c (main) main  main.c:48 | 0x102847a30 (main) owl_sll_binsert  singly_linked_list.c:88 | 0x102847ab8 (main) node_init  singly_linked_list.c:60 | 0x180dffd00 (libsystem_malloc.dylib) _malloc_zone_malloc_instrumented_or_legacy

Leak: 0x14e7041a0  size=32  zone: MallocStackLoggingLiteZone_0x102a40000   malloc in node_init  C  main
    Call stack: 0x180c6be50 (dyld) start | 0x10284761c (main) main  main.c:48 | 0x102847a30 (main) owl_sll_binsert  singly_linked_list.c:88 | 0x102847ac4 (main) node_init  singly_linked_list.c:61 | 0x180dffd00 (libsystem_malloc.dylib) _malloc_zone_malloc_instrumented_or_legacy
```

singly_linked_list.c

```c
#include "singly_linked_list.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

/* Opaque type */

typedef struct SinglyLinkedList
{
    owl_sll_node_t *head;
    owl_sll_node_t *tail;
    u_long length;
    size_t size;
    void (*elfree)(void *item);
} owl_sll_t;

//

owl_sll_t *owl_sll_init(size_t size, void (*elfree)(void *item))
{
    owl_sll_t *list = malloc(sizeof(owl_sll_t));
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    list->length = 0;
    list->size = size;
    list->elfree = elfree;
    return list;
}

void owl_sll_free(owl_sll_t *list)
{
    if (!list->length)
    {
        free(list);
        return;
    }

    owl_sll_node_t *cursor = list->head;

    while (cursor)
    {
        if (list->elfree)
            list->elfree(cursor->data);
        else
            free(cursor->data);

        free(cursor);
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }

    free(list);
}

static owl_sll_node_t *node_init(void *data, size_t size)
{
    static unsigned int id = 0;
    owl_sll_node_t *node = malloc(sizeof(owl_sll_node_t));
    node->data = malloc(size);

    // copy the content of the data
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        *(char *)(node->data + i) = *(char *)(data + i);

    node->next = NULL;
    node->id = id++;
    return node;
}

static void node_free(owl_sll_t *list, owl_sll_node_t *node)
{
    if (!node) return;
    // break any link if exist
    node->next = NULL;

    if (list->elfree)
        list->elfree(node->data);
    else
        free(node->data);

    free(node);
}

void owl_sll_binsert(owl_sll_t *list, void *data)
{
    owl_sll_node_t *node = node_init(data, list->size);
    if (!list->head)
    {
        list->head = node;
        list->tail = node;
    }
    else
    {
        list->tail->next = node;
        list->tail = node;
    }
    list->length++;
}

void *owl_sll_bremove(owl_sll_t *list)
{
    if (!list->length) return NULL;
    owl_sll_node_t *cursor = list->head;

    while (cursor->next && cursor->next->next)
    {
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }

    void *data = cursor->data;

    node_free(list, cursor->next);
    list->tail = cursor;
    list->tail->next = NULL;
    list->length--;

    if (list->length == 0)
    {
        list->head = NULL;
        list->tail = NULL;
    }

    return data;
}

void owl_sll_finsert(owl_sll_t *list, void *data)
{
    owl_sll_node_t *node = node_init(data, list->size);
    if (!list->head)
    {
        list->head = node;
        list->tail = node;
    }
    else
    {
        node->next = list->head;
        list->head = node;
    }
    list->length++;
}

void *owl_sll_fremove(owl_sll_t *list)
{
    if (!list->length) return NULL;

    void *data = list->head->data;
    owl_sll_node_t *node_to_free = list->head;

    list->head = list->head->next;
    node_free(list, node_to_free);
    list->length--;

    if (list->length == 0)
    {
        list->head = NULL;
        list->tail = NULL;
    }

    return data;
}

void owl_sll_print(owl_sll_t *list, void (*format)(void *data), char *connection_sym)
{
    if (!list->length)
    {
        printf("EMPTY\n");
        return;
    }

    owl_sll_node_t *cursor = list->head;
    char *conn_sym = connection_sym ? connection_sym : "->";

    while (cursor)
    {
        format(cursor->data);
        printf(" %s ", conn_sym);
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }

    printf("END\n");
}

// Getters

owl_sll_node_t *owl_sll_head(owl_sll_t *list)
{
    return list->head;
}

owl_sll_node_t *owl_sll_tail(owl_sll_t *list)
{
    return list->tail;
}

unsigned long int owl_sll_length(owl_sll_t *list)
{
    return list->length;
}
```

singly_linked_list.h

```c
#ifndef linked_list_h
#define linked_list_h

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    unsigned int id;
    void *data;
    struct Node *next;
} owl_sll_node_t;

typedef struct SinglyLinkedList owl_sll_t;

owl_sll_t *owl_sll_init(size_t size, void (*elfree)(void *item));
void owl_sll_free(owl_sll_t *list);
void owl_sll_binsert(owl_sll_t *list, void *data);
void *owl_sll_bremove(owl_sll_t *list);
void owl_sll_finsert(owl_sll_t *list, void *data);
void *owl_sll_fremove(owl_sll_t *list);
void owl_sll_print(owl_sll_t *list, void (*format)(void *data), char *connector_symbol);

// Getters

owl_sll_node_t *owl_sll_head(owl_sll_t *list);
owl_sll_node_t *owl_sll_tail(owl_sll_t *list);
unsigned long int owl_sll_length(owl_sll_t *list);

#endif /* linked_list_h */
```

main.c

```c
#include "data_structure/singly_linked_list.h"
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct a
{
    int id;
} a_t;

typedef struct b
{
    int id;
    a_t *a;
} b_t;

void elfree(void *item)
{
    b_t *b = item;
    free(b->a);
    free(b);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    printf("OWL \n");
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    a_t *a1 = malloc(sizeof(a_t));
    a1->id = 1;

    a_t *a2 = malloc(sizeof(a_t));
    a2->id = 2;

    owl_sll_t *list = owl_sll_init(sizeof(b_t), elfree);
    owl_sll_binsert(list, &(b_t){.id = 1, .a=a1 });
    owl_sll_binsert(list, &(b_t){.id = 2, .a=a2 });

    owl_sll_free(list);
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with a program instead of incomplete snippets of code.  For instance, you have not provided us with your header files so we cannot compile your code.   The two 16 bytes is probably a1 and a2 in main that you don't free, and duplicate in `owl_sll_binsert()`

Comment: In `owl_sll_free()` you `free(cursor)` then the next line is `cursor = cursor->next` which is undefined behavior.  You need a temporary point to the element you are removing and advance cursor before you the free.

Comment: You added another snippet.  It's way easier to help you if you concatenate those snippet into a single file program.  Compile that to ensure it works, and update error message to match this file.  Then minimize so we don't have to wade through code that works.  [mre].

Comment: @AllanWind Yes you are correct. The two 16 bytes was from a1 and a2 that I forgot to free. The problem is the other two 32 bytes blocks. I've update the code snippets and included the header file as-well.

Comment: u_long is not declared.  Use size_t instead, btw.

Comment: @AllanWind Your suggestion to create a temporary before I free the cursor fixed the issue. Now I am not getting any leaks. Thank you for your help. Next time I'll try to create a MRE instead of posting the snippets.

Comment: `elfree` defined in main.c is not used anywhere. Why do you need it? `elfree` pointer in the list struct is null. You are calling `free` on the data. Where is the data allocated?

Comment: @AllanWind u_long is from `sys/types.h`. types.h has typedef's for long types.

Comment: @n.m. elfree willl be the function provided by the user to free any deeply nested structures. During the initialization of the list, user can pass the elfree func if they have a nested structure in node's data that needs to cleaned up. The goal is to provide a flexible way to free the data. If there are no nested structured and the data can be freed normally, elfree can be NULL. In owl_sll_free, in the loop i am checking if the user has provided a custom cleanup func(elfree) and if provided calling it instead.

Comment: You doon't need to tell me that. I understand what it is supposed go do. I am not asking you that. I am asking you what it in factual actuality *does*, not in some hypothetical future user code but in the program that you show us. What `elfree` in `main.c` *does*? (Nothing, it is not used anywhere). What `elfree` inside the list *does*? (Nothing, it is a null pointer). So where is the pointer that is *actually* passed to `free` *actually* allocated? (You fill in the answer).

Comment: @n.m. Sorry my bad. You are absolutely correct, let me remove the code from the snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In `main()` you need to free `a1` and `a2`.
2. In owl_sll_free() you have a use after free undefined behavior:

```
        free(cursor);
        cursor = cursor->next;
```

instead you want to a `tmp` pointer to cursor, advance cursor, then free what tmp pointers to:

```
void owl_sll_free(owl_sll_t *list) {
    for(owl_sll_node_t *cursor = list->head; cursor;) {
        owl_sll_node_t *tmp = cursor;
        cursor = cursor->next;
        if (list->elfree)
            list->elfree(tmp->data);
        else
            free(tmp->data);
        free(tmp);
    }
    free(list);
}
```

I don't have the `leaks` program but valgrind is happy after those two changes:

```
==553760== HEAP SUMMARY:
==553760==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==553760==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees, 1,152 bytes allocated
==553760== 
==553760== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

Bonus suggestion:

In `owl_sll_init()` if you fallback to free:

```
    list->elfree = elfree ? elfree : free;
```

Then you can eliminate the conditional in own_sll_free():

```
void owl_sll_free(owl_sll_t *list) {
    for(owl_sll_node_t *cursor = list->head; cursor;) {
        owl_sll_node_t *tmp = cursor;
        cursor = cursor->next;
        list->elfree(tmp->data);
        free(tmp);
    }
    free(list);
}
```